# How can I control the empty cart text in Drupal Ubercart

Tags: drupal, ubercart

Options...

1) create a block that tests for and empty $order session type object.

2) find the configuration text area in the tangled ubercart admin area.

3) hack the module to call a block on empty cart rather than the hard coded text (if that's true.)

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do...?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is you want to do, but if you just need to change text, then the [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module works well for that.

Comment: I would soooo much rather get to the hook source. I have avoided String Overrides like the plague. Doing regex replaces on every t() function call sounds like a horrible idea to me.